# How to modify the code below to present the bias of three estimators?

Tags: r

I have a Uniform distribution with parameters (0,$\theta$),
and I have calculated its MME, and the other two estimators.
I also calculated their individual bias in my code.
But I am having trouble properly plot the three biases in one plot.
I wonder would you mind providing me with any suggestion that how can I modify the "matplot" part. Maybe the question lies there? Thank you very much!!

```
n <- 1000
theta <- 9
x <- runif(n, 0, theta)


theta.hat.mme <-2*mean(x)
theta.hat.G <-(n*theta)/(n+1)
theta.hat.H <-((n+1)/n)*theta.hat.G 

# theta.hat.G is the max of (x_1, x_2,...,x_n) be an estimator of theta, and theta.hat.H is the modified estimator of theta.hat.G to make it unbiased.

#   Empirical Exploration of properties

M   <- 1000   # Number of sample of size n
L   <- 9     # Different values of n
# create storage variables
mme <- numeric(M) 
vn <- numeric(L)
bias <- variance <- matrix(0, nrow=L, ncol=3)

for(l in 1:L)
{
  n <- 20 + (l-1)*10  
  for(m in 1:M)
  {
    x      <- runif(n, 0, theta)

    mme[m] <-  2*mean(x)          
  }  

  bias[l,1] <- mean(mme)-theta
  bias[1,2] <-mean(theta.hat.G)-theta
  bias[1,3] <-mean(theta.hat.H)-theta

  variance[l,1] <- var(mme) 
  variance[1,2] <-var(theta.hat.G)
  variance[1,3] <-var(theta.hat.H)
  vn[l] <- n 
}        

#windows(5,5)
matplot(vn, bias, type='l', col=1:3, lty=1:3, xlab='n')
abline(h=0, lty=3)
legend('topright', col=1:3,
       c('Method of Moments Estimator', 'Theta G', 'Theta H'),
       inset=0.01, lty=1:2)
```

Comment: Do you consider this code to be correct in terms of your calculations? It isn't. As for the plot, what exactly do you find unsatisfactory? Other than perhaps the legend size. Asking for *suggestions* is too broad, opinion-based, and most likely will lead to closing the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! So what you mean is, if my calculation earlier is correct, this code is not correct according to that?

Comment: The plotting question, when edited, is valid in any case. What I meant is a side comment that your numerical results regarding biases are wrong: most of them are zero, but perhaps the code isn't finished yet.

Comment: Thank you, I guess my calculation were wrong. Thanks